# Shared Preference isn't saving my data

Tags: android, save, sharedpreferences

I wonder why my `SharedPreference` method isn't saving my data.
Here's my code

Saving Function (I call this function every time after executing my process):

```
public void save(double tamt) {
    SharedPreferences saveamount = getSharedPreferences("TotalAmount" , MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = saveamount.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.putString("LastAmount",String.valueOf(tamt));
    editor.apply();
}
```

I call the reading method inside my `onCreate()` method:

```
public void loadAmt() {
    SharedPreferences loadamount = getSharedPreferences("TotalAmount" ,0);
    String amt = loadamount.getString("TotalAmount","");
    if (amt.matches("")){
        return;
    }
    else {
        total = Double.parseDouble(loadamount.getString("TotalAmount" ,"0"));
        et.setText(String.valueOf(total));
    }
}
```

Is it because of the saving or reading method?
Every time, after exiting my program and reopening it, the data isn't showing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you save

```
editor.putString("LastAmount",String.valueOf(tamt));
```

But you retrieve

```
String amt = loadamount.getString("TotalAmount","0");
```

They are **different** keys.
You have to retrieve

```
String amt = loadamount.getString("LastAmount","");
```

And this:

```
total = Double.parseDouble(loadamount.getString("TotalAmount" ,"0"));
et.setText(String.valueOf(total));}
```

should be changed to

```
// USELESS, you already have the string in amt
//total = Double.parseDouble(loadamount.getString("TotalAmount" ,"0"));
et.setText(String.valueOf(amt));}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake here is `TotalAmount` is your file name and your're trying to get a string with a key `TotalAmount` that doesn't exist as you saved your value with the key `LastAmount`. So just modify the load method

```
public void loadAmt() {
    SharedPreferences loadamount = getSharedPreferences("TotalAmount" ,0);
    String amt = loadamount.getString("LastAmount","");
    if (amt.matches("")){
        return;
    } else {
        total = Double.parseDouble(loadamount.getString("LastAmount" ,"0"));
        et.setText(String.valueOf(total));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **loadAmt()** method your key is not right to fetch the preference info, do like this:

```
 public void loadAmt()
{
    SharedPreferences loadamount = getSharedPreferences("TotalAmount" ,0);
    String amt = loadamount.getString("LastAmount",""); //change here to LastAmount
    if (amt.matches("")){
        return;
    }
    else {
    total = Double.parseDouble(loadamount.getString("LastAmount" ,"0")); //change here to LastAmount
    et.setText(String.valueOf(total));}

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Following will be your code:**

```
public void save(double tamt) {
            SharedPreferences saveamount = getSharedPreferences("TotalAmount" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = saveamount.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.putString("LastAmount",String.valueOf(tamt));
            editor.commit();}
```

I use the reading function inside my OnCreate Function

```
 public void loadAmt()
{
    SharedPreferences loadamount = getSharedPreferences("TotalAmount" ,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String amt = loadamount.getString("LastAmount","");
    if (amt.matches("")){
        return;
    }else {
    total = Double.parseDouble(loadamount.getString("LastAmount" ,"0"));
    et.setText(String.valueOf(total));}

  }
```